# About the inject method: How does it work?

Tags: ruby

This part of code calculates the value of each arithmetic series up to and including the number that the user put in:

```
print "enter a number: "
num = gets.to_i
(1..num).inject(0) do |res, e|
  res += e
  p res
end
```

I think that `(1..num)` is the range, with `num` being the user input. I know that `inject` combines all elements of enum by applying a binary operation specified by a block or a symbol that names a method or operator.

I don't understand what each element in this line does:

```
(1..num).inject(0) do |res, e|
```

- What does `|res, e|` mean? It must be the block that defines what `inject` does, but what does for instance `res` and `e` stand for? (`e` is probably element?)
- What does `(0)` stand for?
- What does the command `do` do?
- what is its connection in regard to `(1..num)` and `inject(0)`?
- Am I right to assume that `p` at the end just stands for `puts` or `print`?

Comment: You can combine the block's two lines: `p res + e`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inject` takes an optional start value, and a block taking an intermediate value and element and returning a new intermediate value.

So:

> What does (0) stand for?

The start value parameter to `inject`.

> What does the command "do" do?

It is not a command; it marks the start of the block (terminated by `end`). `.inject(0) do ... end` is almost (except for some syntactic issues) the same as `.inject(0) { ... }`. Usually, `do ... end` is used for multi-line blocks and `{ ... }` for single-line blocks, but it is not a rule.

> What does |res, e| mean?

Those are the block parameters (intermediate value and current element), here probably called after "result" and "element", respectively.

Let's see on a simplified example: `(1..3).inject(0) do |res, e| res + e end` will set the intermediate result to `0`. Then it will pass this intermediate result and the first element of the enumerable being injected: `res` is `0` and `e` is `1`. The value of the block is the value of its last expression, which is `1` (result of `0 + 1`). This `1` now becomes the new intermediate value, and `2` becomes the next current element. The value of the block is `3` (result of `1 + 2`). In the next iteration, intermediate value is `3`, and the current element also `3`, resulting in `6` (`3 + 3`). The range will stop yielding elements now that we reached its upper boundary, and `inject` returns with the last intermediate result calculated, `6`.

> Also, the last question am I right to assume that "p" at the end just stands for puts or print?

Almost. `p` is its own beast. `p x` is roughly synonymous with `puts x.inspect; x` - i.e. it prints the value in a bit different format, and unlike `puts` which always returns `nil`, `p` returns the value unchanged. Thus, `p res` at the end of your block will not destroy the code by making it return `nil`, but transparently return `res`.

Answer (score 3):

`inject` is a method that boils a collection (eg an array or range) down to a single value. It does this by executing the block once for each element in the collection. The block takes two arguments: the current value being worked on, and the single value that will eventually be returned. `inject` itself takes one argument (aside from the block), which is its initial starting value.

Take this example.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].inject(0) do |result, current|
  result + current
end
```

We have a list of numbers, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. We're going to boil them down into one single number.

We start with `0`, because that's `inject`'s argument. That means that the first time the block runs, `result` will be 0.

So the block runs for the first time. `result` is 0, `current` is 1, the first element. We say `result + current` (which is `1`). It's the last expression inside the block, so it's what that block 'returns'.

At the end of the block, `inject` says "Okay, do we have more elements in the collection?" Yeah. So the block runs again. *This time*, `result` is whatever the last block returned, which was 1, and `current` is the second element, `2`.

The block runs, and finishes with `result + current`, or 1 + 2, which is 3. There are still elements left, so we run again. This time, `result` is 3, and `current` is 3. `result + current`, 6. Still more values to go, on the next run `result` is 6 and `current` is 4. 6 + 4 = 10. Still more values to go, on the next run `result` is 10 and `current` is 5. 10 + 5 = 15.

Then the block finishes, and there are no more elements left. So `inject` itself returns with the final value, 15. So in the end, `x = 15`. We boiled down our list into one number by adding things up.

`res` in your example stands for result, and `e` for element. You can call them anything you want. You might call them `sum` while adding, or `product` if multiplying. But they don't have to be numbers. You could use `inject` to boil an array of strings, a range of characters, an array of arrays, whatever collection you want. The block just tells it how.

Answer (score 1):

Excited to see that you're learning Ruby, welcome!

At your level of expertise best learn from a book.

- Get yourself a copy of the ["Pickaxe Book"](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby) — this is by far the best book.
- The first edition fir Ruby 1.9 is available online, http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby
- And here is a popular online tutorial, http://poignant.guide

Some quick answers

- `1..num` is a range object
- `.inject(0) do ... end` is a method call with TWO parameters, the value `0` and a code block
- `do |a, b| ... end` is a code block with two parameters
- `res` and `e` are VERY bad variable names, maybe better use `sum` and `each`?
- `p` is a global method that prints debug information, similar to `puts` but not the same

Hope that helps to unblock you.